# call bootstrap with a Shared-Service in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript2.0

I'm using Angular 5.0.3 and created the App by cli.angular.io. In my App.module.ts file I found:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [...],
  providers: [...],
  bootstrap [AppComponent]
})
```

In other older questions I found answers just like to call

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [SharedService]);
```

to hold a SharedService as global as possible. How this bootstrap call works in the new Angular-5 environment?

The main problem is that I would like to navigateByUrl to an other router-outlet page without loosing the SharedService content.

Comment: I don't think I understand your question properly but services are shared between modules so if you have another module which needs to access the same instance of the service it'll work through DI.

Answer (score 2):

i think you should inject your service this way:

```
@NgModule({
 declarations: [...],
 imports: [...],
 providers: [SharedService],
 bootstrap [AppComponent]
})
```

That will create a unique singleton shared throughout the entire app.

Answer (score 0):

Has been cleared. Initialize a global SharedService in the AppModule in the @NgModule decorator in the providers object part. Provide it nowhere else. In foreign objects use the constructor to let inject the SharedService.

Be aware where and how (often) to fill the SharedService with data. My problem was to fill the data more than once.